# tryCatch - namespace?

Tags: r, try-catch, assign

I am quite new to R and I am confused by the correct usage of `tryCatch`. My goal is to make a prediction for a large data set. If the predictions cannot fit into memory, I want to circumvent the problem by splitting my data.

Right now, my code looks roughly as follows:

```
tryCatch({
  large_vector = predict(model, large_data_frame)
}, error = function(e) { # I ran out of memory
  for (i in seq(from = 1, to = dim(large_data_frame)[1], by = 1000)) {
    small_vector = predict(model, large_data_frame[i:(i+step-1), ])
    save(small_vector, tmpfile)
  }
  rm(large_data_frame) # free memory
  large_vector = NULL
  for (i in seq(from = 1, to = dim(large_data_frame)[1], by = 1000)) {
    load(tmpfile)
    unlink(tmpfile)
    large_vector = c(large_vector, small_vector)
  }
})
```

The point is that if no error occurs, `large_vector` is filled with my predictions as expected. If an error occurs, `large_vector` seems to exist only in the namespace of the error code - which makes sense because I declared it as a function. For the same reason, I get a warning saying that `large_data_frame` cannot be removed.

Unfortunately, this behavior is not what I want. I would want to assign the variable `large_vector` from within my error function. I figured that one possibility is to specify the environment and use assign. Thus, I would use the following statements in my error code:

```
rm(large_data_frame, envir = parent.env(environment()))
[...]
assign('large_vector', large_vector, parent.env(environment()))
```

However, this solution seems rather dirty to me. I wonder whether there is any possibility to achieve my goal with "clean" code?

[EDIT]
There seems to be some confusion because I put the code above mainly to illustrate the problem, not to give a working example. Here's a minimal example that shows the namespace issue:

```
# Example 1 : large_vector fits into memory
rm(large_vector)
tryCatch({
  large_vector = rep(5, 1000)
}, error = function(e) {
  # do stuff to build the vector
  large_vector = rep(3, 1000)
})
print(large_vector)  # all 5

# Example 2 : pretend large_vector does not fit into memory; solution using parent environment
rm(large_vector)
tryCatch({ 
  stop();  # simulate error
}, error = function(e) {
  # do stuff to build the vector
  large_vector = rep(3, 1000)
  assign('large_vector', large_vector, parent.env(environment()))
})
print(large_vector)  # all 3

# Example 3 : pretend large_vector does not fit into memory; namespace issue
rm(large_vector)
tryCatch({ 
  stop();  # simulate error
}, error = function(e) {
  # do stuff to build the vector
  large_vector = rep(3, 1000)
})
print(large_vector)  # does not exist
```

Comment: check the second edit of my answer, I added a small tip there which could come in handy in some situations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do something like this :

```
res <- tryCatch({
  large_vector = predict(model, large_data_frame)
}, error = function(e) { # I ran out of memory
  ll <- lapply(split(data,seq(1,nrow(large_data_frame),1000)),
         function(x)
             small_vector = predict(model, x))
  return(ll)
})
rm(large_data_frame)
if(is.list(ll)) 
  res <- do.call(rbind,res)
```

The idea is to return a list of predictions results if you run out of the memory.

NOTE, i am not sure of the result here, because we don't have a reproducible example.

Comment: That actually does work! I tried returning variables from the error function before, however I missed assigning the return of the `tryCatch` call to a variable (`res` in this case). Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jenny Note that you can use deallocate here in the finally block. `finally = {rm(large_data_frame)}`.

Comment: +1, this is much nicer solution than the one I tried to make in the spirit of the original question. And @agstudy's comment makes my answers small merit pointless :)

Comment: @Hemmo I see that :) but I like your idea of simplified version to explain your purpose ( explain code by code).

Comment: there seems to be a small bug in the solution... instead of `if(is.list(ll)) ` it should be `if(is.list(res))`

Comment: Gosh this was a 9 year old answer. Still if there was a bug let;s correct it for people who land up here.

Answer (score 4):

**EDIT: Let's try again:**

You can use `finally` argument of `tryCatch`:

```
step<-1000
n<-dim(large_data_frame)[1]
large_vector <- NULL
tryCatch({
  large_vector <- predict(model, large_data_frame) 
}, error = function(e) { # ran out of memory
  for (i in seq(from = 1, to = n, by = step)) {
    small_vector <- predict(model, large_data_frame[i:(i+step-1),]) #predict in pieces
    save(small_vector,file=paste0("tmpfile",i)) #same pieces
  }  
 rm(large_data_frame) #free memory

},finally={if(is.null(large_vector)){ #if we run out of memory
   large_vector<-numeric(n) #make vector
   for (i in seq(from = 1, to = n, by = step)){
     #collect pieces
     load(paste0("tmpfile",i)) 
     large_vector[i:(i+step-1)] <- small_vector
   }
}})
```

Here's a simplified version to see what is going on:

```
large_vector<-NULL
rm(y)
tryCatch({
  large_vector <- y 
}, error = function(e) {# y is not found
  print("error")
},finally={if(is.null(large_vector)){
 large_vector<-1
}})
> large_vector
[1] 1
```

**EDIT2:** Another tip regarding the scope which could be useful for you (although maybe not in this situation as you didn't want to declare `large_vector` beforehand): The `<<-` operator, from R-help:

> The operators <<- and ->> are normally only used in functions, and
>   cause a search to made through parent environments for an existing
>   definition of the variable being assigned...

Therefore you could use above example code like this:

```
large_vector<-NULL
rm(y)
tryCatch({
  large_vector <- y 
}, error = function(e) {# y is not found
  large_vector <<- 1
  print("error")
})
> large_vector
[1] 1
```

Comment: The code was intended mainly to illustrate my problem, therefore I said it looks "roughly" like this. Sorry it is not reproducible this way. Actually your solution requires me to allocate large_vector before the tryCatch clause, which is not possible due to memory restrictions. Also, the assignment of large_vector inside the error function will still not take place (since it is still a function with own namespace)

Comment: Ok, I though that the problem was in the memory allocation inside of `predict` function, not in allocating the `large_vector`. But you are right about the second point, the assignment wont of course work here. Sorry.

Comment: @Jenny, I edited my answer to show another solution. Although @agstudy's answer is more neat as it doesn't need any temporary files etc, this might be useful as an example of `finally` argument in `tryCatch`.

Answer (score 0):

The code below is quite self explanatory. Indeed the problem is that anything inside the error function is not by default applied to the parent environment.

> b=0
>
> ## as explained, this doesn't work:
>
> tryCatch(expr = {stop("error1")}, error=function(e) {b=1})
> b
>
> ## SOLUTION 1: assign to the parent environment
>
> tryCatch(expr = {stop("error2")}, error=function(e) {assign(x = "b", value =
> 2, envir = parent.env(env = environment()))})
> b
>
> ## SOLUTION 2: the most simple (only works if you are assigning to b in both `expr` and `error`)
>
> b = tryCatch(expr = {stop("error3")}, error=function(e) {b=3;return(b)})
> b